# How to add to exception to Adblock by click to button

Tags: javascript, cookies, adblock

I have function in JS that detect adblock on site and I want to click button and add site to exceptions, reload page and extension adblock should change color to green and add this site to exceptions.

Add site to exceptions

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.